# Deploying VSTO Add-In to All Users

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, vsto, office-2013

I add a `Word 2013 Add-In` project for add ribbon to word.

I Release it. it added ribbon to word for current user, but i want add it to all user.

I set registry in windows.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\General\
```

Set `EnableLocalMachineVSTO=1` for it.

but don't add it to all user.

Comment: Are your Office and OS both 64-bit, both 32-bit, or one of each? This affects where the registry keys are placed. Also, can you show a screen cap of the registry keys you entered, their values, and the manifest for the project. Usually these issues are either wrong keys, keys in the wrong place, or manifest errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to register the add-in for all users. See [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386106(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

I'd suggest creating an installer for the add-in to get it deployed easily. The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx) article describes all the required steps for creating MSI instanllers.

Comment: Thanks, i want to run this for all user in my system without created setup project. I set setting in registry keys. I use ` D:\\MyAddIn\\bin\\Release\\MyAddIn.vsto|vstolocal` for mainfest key. but don't show add-in.